# How to run Android L Preview Sample On Android 5.0 / Nexus 7

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the Android 'L' Preview Camera2VideoSample app to run on Android 5.0 on a Nexus 7.  I've gotten the app to build successfully but when I try to push it to the device I get the following message in the "Choose Device" pop-up window:

LaunchCompatibility{compatible=NO, reason=minSdk(API 21, android-21.1.0 preview) != deviceSdk(API 21)

My build.gradle looks like this:

```
compileSdkVersion "android-21"

buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"
```

And the manifest looks like this:

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="android-21.1.0" android:targetSdkVersion="android-21.1.0" />

Any advice on how to get this app to actually run would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the L preview image is actually api 20, while your project is complied at 21.

Comment: I solved this by creating a "Hello World" application at API level 21 and basically copying the two resulting build.gradle files into the other project with just a few minor changes.